# accessing child elements of <List>pojo class

Tags: java, xml, spring, list, validation

i created an Employee list of POJO .

```
public class Employee 
{   public String name; 
    public String Key; 
    private string Value; 
getters and setters.
}
```

another class

I am adding condition that if employee childelements /Key size()is <=4 then implement this code.

I tried doing this `if(getemployee().getkey().size() <= 4){ do something}`

issue getkey() is string. 
edited here.
rookie mistake.since its a forloop. i did count.to limit if(count<=4).
Thanks in advance, my apology for syntax i typed very quick.

Comment: my bad. just updated. what i want basically is to set somehow size for getkey string to be not more then 4. or may be create list of getkey out of employee. completely lost.

Comment: First get basic syntax right: if statements need parenthesis. Then name your methods to make your code more clear: getEmployee returns a List, so rename it to getEmployees. This way it be easier for you to spot your error (and please, format your code). Also, get a decent IDE, it will mark your syntax errors and give you hints what methods are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a structure like the one given below:

```
public class Parent{
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees){
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return employees;
    }
    //...
}
```

Then, you can do like

```
Parent p = new Parent();
if(p.getEmployees().size() <= 4) {
    //do something
}
```